# Using NSTimer / time dependancy in method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

At the moment in my app when a user exits to a UIWebView then comes back the app shows them a rating pop up. I do this in the `if` statement of my method.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear
 {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

 if  (self.appExitedToWebView) {
     [self.presentationController showAdvertsWithOfferID:self.offerDetailViewController.offer.offerID completionBlock:nil];
 }
}
```

However, I am wanting to only show the rating if the user has been on the UIWebView for over 15 minutes. How would I add this dependency on my method? I am guessing it is something to do with `NSTimer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `start` method when you show UIWebView and then after your mentioned time gets completed a method with be called `timerFired` and then you can set bool that user has completed your mentioned time.

```
-(void)start
{
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:yourtime target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)timerFired

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:yourtime target:self selector:@selector(showAlert) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)showAlert {
   [timer invalidate];
   [self.presentationController showAdvertsWithOfferID:self.offerDetailViewController.offer.offerID completionBlock:nil];
}
```

Comment: Where would this fit into my existing method?

Comment: Just put this code in your if condition..